# Right JOIN retornando registros mais recentes

Tags: mysql, join

**Tenho o seguinte cenário:**

**Tabela Equipamentos**

[image: Tabela Equipamentos]

**Tabela Manutenções**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Temos o seguinte Right JOIN:**

```
select * from equipamentos e 
right join manutencoes m 
on e.patrimonio = m.patrimonio 
group by m.patrimonio;
```

[image: join]

Nesta consulta realizo um GROUP BY patrimonio e os dados obtidos conforme a figura abaixo:

```
select * from equipamentos e 
right join manutencoes m 
on e.patrimonio = m.patrimonio 
group by m.patrimonio;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Dúvida:** Gostaria de saber como faria para trazer no group by o registro mais recente (de maior id) conforme a próxima figura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"como faria para trazer no group by o registro mais recente (de maior id)"* eu acho que a própria dúvida já responde, ou seja, para o maior ID use `MAX(id)`

```
select e.patrimonio, 
       e.descricao,
       MAX(e.id_manutencao) id_manutencao,
       .... demais campos ...
 from equipamentos e 
 right join manutencoes m 
    on e.patrimonio = m.patrimonio 
 group by m.patrimonio;
```

Eu prefixei os campos com "e" ou seja, tabela equipamentos, mas pode nomear corretamente, o importante é usar o `MAX`.

Outro ponto, pode ser necessário adicionar os demais campos ao `GROUP BY` (patrimonio, descricao, etc)